# Using the cURL command, how does one fetch stock data which comes back *without* commas and spaces?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, osx, curl

What can I add to the below script so that it fetches the stock data and brings it back WITHOUT any commas and spaces? For example GOOG Outstanding shares is 675,000,000.

I desire the output of 675000000 for my txt file. (no spaces or commas or punctuation). I need decimal functionality however for share prices though).

```
cd desktop/quoteUpdate
while true
do
 curl -o quotes.txt -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=avxl,goog,aapl&f=snl1c6j2s6f6"
 sed -i '.bak' 's/,/ /g' quotes.txt # replace commas with spaces
echo UPDATED:
date
sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that while the url would suggest it is a CSV, it really is not - the share volumes that contain commas are not properly quoted. That said you'll need to employ additional knowledge. In this case, try changing the format of the output from:

```
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=avxl,goog,aapl&f=snl1c6j2s6f6
```

producing:

```
"AVXL","ANAVEX LIFE SCIEN",0.1799,"-0.0041",    38,260,000,0,    23,703,000
"GOOG","Google Inc.",500.87,"+4.69",   678,365,000,67.911B,   572,967,000
"AAPL","Apple Inc.",109.80,"-0.42",  5,864,839,000,182.8B,  5,856,335,000
```

to e.g.:

```
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=avxl,goog,aapl&f=sl1c6sj2ss6sf6
```

which  yields:

```
"AVXL",0.1799,"-0.0041","AVXL",    38,260,000,"AVXL",0,"AVXL",    23,703,000
"GOOG",500.87,"+4.69","GOOG",   678,365,000,"GOOG",67.911B,"GOOG",   572,967,000
"AAPL",109.80,"-0.42","AAPL",  5,864,839,000,"AAPL",182.8B,"AAPL",  5,856,335,000
```

You can then parse this with e.g.:

```
sed 's/"[A-Z][^"]*",/ & /g' \
| awk -- '{
        gsub("\"", "", $2);
        gsub(",", "", $4);
        gsub(",", "", $8);
        print $1 $2 $4 "," $6 $8
    }'
```

which will give you something more CSV-like:

```
"AVXL",0.1799,-0.0041,38260000,0,23703000
"GOOG",500.87,+4.69,678365000,67.911B,572967000
"AAPL",109.80,-0.42,5864839000,182.8B,5856335000
```

The trick is that the ticker symbol is a well-matchable thing and you can thus use it as an anchor where you need it.

The magic incantation above does this:

- the `sed` invocation surrounds the occurrences of the ticker symbols (which are double quoted strings beginning with a capital letter) with spaces, thus marking it effectively a white-spaces separated lists
- `awk` first replaces all double quotes (first line) and commas (second and third line) in fields 2 (to prevent the price change field being double quoted and thus being treated as a string instead of a floating point number if you then start processing it with a spreadsheet) and 4 and 8 respectively. The last line prints the modified fields (and omits the now superfluous additional ticker symbols).

Thus in the end you can do it like this:

```
curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=avxl,goog,aapl&f=sl1c6sj2ss6sf6' \
| sed 's/"[A-Z][^"]*",/ & /g' \
| awk -- '{
        gsub("\"", "", $2);
        gsub(",", "", $4);
        gsub(",", "", $8);
        print $1 $2 $4 "," $6 $8
    }'
```

Note the `\` backslashes at the end of the lines - these make sure, that the commands are not invoked separately, but rather as if they were on one line. This notation is used to enhance readability. The backslashes are not used in the four line AWK script, since that is surrounded by quotes and the new lines are thus part of the whole command. And be sure to read some basic tutorials on UNIX shell scripting - it will save you lots of time later on.

Also note the quotes around the URL - these make sure that special characters (`&` in this case) don't get interpreted by the shell.

Comment: really appreciate taking the time to help me. I will input that code and see if that works. May I revert back to you if I have an issue. I am only new to programming. Thanks Chris (Scotland)

Comment: Hey Peter I cant get this to run properly. Can you have a look below code please and see if I have done something wrong. The excerpt you put in the E.G part above was the same as the original line of code (don't know if that was intended)           cd desktop/quoteUpdate
while true
do
 curl -o quotes.txt -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=avxl,goog,aapl&f=snl1c6j2s6f6"
sed 's/"[A-Z][^"]*",/ & /g' \
| awk -- '{
        gsub("\"", "", $2);
        gsub(",", "", $4);
        gsub(",", "", $8);
        print $1 $2 $4 "," $6 $8
    }'
echo UPDATED:
date
sleep 10
done

Comment: @ChrisDormani The excerpt in the E.G.part is not quite the same; the last argument to the URI is different. In your original code it says `snl1c6j2s6f6`, but in @peterph's example, it says `sl1c6sj2ss6sf6`.

Comment: Break it into several steps, and then put it together. First download the data into a file (e.g. `curl ... > quotes.txt`), then run `sed` on it (e.g. `sed 's/...' < quotes.txt > quotes.fields`, and last run `awk` (`awk -- '{...' quotes.fields`. In each step you shhhould be able to verify you got it right. As Jenny points out, use the changed URL - I have modified the output format.

Comment: It can, but when you need to find where the problem is, you need to split it into pieces. :) But the culprit here is clear - you were not using the right url.

Comment: No - the output as you see it in the answer is produced only by the commands therein. You can pipe `curl` output straight to the `sed | awk` combo.

Comment: "pipe curl output to `sed | awk`" means `curl ... | sed ... | awk ...`. Check some UNIX shell scripting tutorials to get an idea how it works. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-pipes-filters.htm might or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix) might help. I'll also update the answer.

Comment: Peter it is running now which is some what progress (as I copied your code verbatim ) BUT it comes up with "missing format variable" when I run the executable.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really help with that, if you copied it verbatim. You may try to split it into parts as I suggested a couple of comments above and try to find out where the message comes from.

Comment: Chris I think you need to embed the curl command in quotes: `curl -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=avxl,goog,aapl&f=sl1c6sj2ss6sf6" | 
sed 's/"[A-Z][^"]*",/ & /g'
| awk -- '{
        gsub("\"", "", $2);
        gsub(",", "", $4);
        gsub(",", "", $8);
        print $1 $2 $4 "," $6 $8
    }'`

Comment: @suspectus very right you are, I completely forgot about that - fixed now.